# New MEV Bot on Solana. Need a program to automatically click prompts

Tags: automation, click, telegram-bot, solana

I will start off by saying that I have no clue how to how to code/ how to run code. I have a Mac and I know python can run on Mac's but I do not know how to even run that.

So I was manually clicking on the prompts to start the MEV bot process. Made decent money that is technically "free". It is only a two click process. First click is on " Start MEV AI", then a new prompt pops up and the next button to click on reads "✅ Lets go!"

I think it becomes more advanced because the bot will have to go back up to the top and select " Start MEV AI" again, instead of selecting a prompt from the most recent message (just getting this from a different discussion I read here). The wait time for transactions to pop up is about 4 hours right now; so once the first confitmation comes though I could stop running the bot.

Now this is only the first part of the process, but if I could get a bot to constantly que up MEV attacks, I would have not problem clicking on the button to complete the attack.

Please let me know if there is a code that is public that I can use to run this. I will just ask chat gpt how to run it on python if there is a code for this. Project is called Solana MEV AI.

If one of you can copy their Telegram Bots code and make it perform faster, you will be very successful. If you know of any other TG bots that can do this, please let me know as well so I can check them out.

Thank you!!

I have tried several times to create and launch code, but it never works. My degree in biology does not warrant that and I do not even know where to begin researching how to start.